# How to create mask in winrar to archive folders by name?

Tags: command, mask, rar, winrar

I have folders `C:\testA01`, `C:\testA02` and `C:\testB01`, `C:\testB02`.

How to create a command to archive only folders with `testA` in their name?

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -u -rr8 -y C:\BACKUP\backup.rar C:\testA ?? \*.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows command line interpreter does not support wildcards in folder paths. It is only possible to search for folders matching a pattern with **DIR** or **FOR**.

But take a look on text file **WhatsNew.txt** in program files directory of *WinRAR* version 5.30 or any later version. There can be read:

> 5. Folder wildcards are allowed in RAR command line in file names to
>       archive. For example:
>
>    rar a backup c:\backup\2015*\*
>
>    will archive all '2015*' folders in c:\backup. Use -r switch to search
>       for '2015*' also in c:\backup subfolders.

*WinRAR* v5.30 can be used on Windows XP and later Windows.

A command line for your backup task is for example:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" u -cfg- -ep1 -idq -r -rr8 -y C:\BACKUP\backup.rar C:\testA*\*
```

For details on the used command `u` which is like command `a` with switch `-u` and the used switches see text file **Rar.txt** being the manual for the console version `Rar.exe` of *WinRAR*.

Of course you can also run from command line the GUI version, but one switch must be changed:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" u -cfg- -ep1 -ibck -r -rr8 -y C:\BACKUP\backup.rar C:\testA*\*
```

The switch `-ibck` for running GUI version in background (minimized to system tray)  is used instead of `-idq` which means for console version to run in quiet mode with only error messages printed into console window.

The commands and switches for the GUI version with some differences to console version are explained in help of *WinRAR*. Start *WinRAR*, click in menu **Help** on menu item **Help topics**, select tab **Contents**, open item **Command line mode** and read the pages listed below this list item.